Image presheaf over affine variety which is not a sheaf
I was thinking about situations where the image presheaf is not a sheaf, specifically in the context of algebraic geometry. The first algebraic geometry example I saw comes from exercise II.1.21(c) of Hartshorne.
Let $X=\mathbb{P}^1_k$, let $Y=\{P,Q\}$, a set of two points in $X$, and let $\mathscr{I}_Y$ be the ideal sheaf of $Y$, i.e. $\mathscr{I}_Y(U)$ is the ideal of functions in $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ vanishing on $Y$. Then there is an exact sequence of sheaves of modules
$$0\to\mathscr{I}_Y\to\mathcal{O}_X\to i_*(\mathcal{O}_Y)\to 0$$
where $i:Y\to X$ is the inclusion. Now, for any proper open set $U\subsetneq X$, the homomorphism $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)\to\Gamma(U,i_*(\mathcal{O}_Y))$ is surjective (i.e. any regular function on $U\cap Y$ can be extended to $U$), but for $U=X$, this is the homomorphism $k\to k\times k$ which is not surjective. So this is a simple example where the image presheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X\to i_*(\mathcal{O}_Y)$ is not a sheaf.
This made me wonder whether there exists an affine example. In other words, my question is

Let $X$ be an affine variety over an algebraically closed field $k$, let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, and let $\varphi:\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ be a homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Is the image presheaf necessarily a sheaf? If not, what if we assume $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are coherent or quasi-coherent?

By replacing $\mathcal{G}$ with the image sheaf $\text{im}(\varphi)$, this is equivalent to asking, if $\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ is a surjective sheaf homomorphism, then is $\mathcal{F}(U)\to\mathcal{G}(U)$ surjective for all open $U\subseteq X$. In the quasi-coherent case, I believe my question is equivalent to asking

Let $R$ be a finite type integral domain over $k$, let $M$ and $N$ be $R$-modules, and let $f:M\to N$ be a surjective homomorphism of $R$-modules. Then is the homomorphism $\widetilde{M}(U)\to\widetilde{N}(U)$ surjective for all open sets $U\subseteq\text{Spec}(R)$?

